# Binding a method to class instance on fly in Python

Tags: python, function, class, methods, instance

```py
class mc:
    def show(self):
        self.func()


a = mc()
def myfunc(self):
    print('instance function')
a.func = myfunc
a.show()
```

The above does not work: `TypeError: myfunc() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'`.

Why is the instance name not automatically inserted by Python, considering that I'm using dot notation?

Comment: If you want to make an instance method, just make it an instance method in the regular way. However for your `myfunc` I would expect it to be a regular function that you are just storing as the `func` attrbute of a particuar instance of mc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add a method to a class using [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch).

```py
class mc:
    def show(self):
        self.func()

a = mc()
def myfunc(self):
    print('instance function')
mc.func = myfunc
a.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It can work like this, since the function isn't really an instance method

```
class mc:
    def show(self):
         self.x = 1
         func(self)


a = mc()
def myfunc(self):
    print (self.x)
    print('instance function')
a.func = myfunc
a.show()
```